# Access Database Symfony2

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, orocrm

Does anyone know how to access a database through an interface thats running under a symfony2 application? Like in the way you can see a database with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you using Doctrine? With Doctrine you can access the database in an ORM manner (by DQL) or on a DB level (by SQL). Otherwise I would not fully understand what you want to achieve / what your question is.

Comment: A database running under Symfony2 is not different from another database, you can view it with PhpMyAdmin. Your question is unclear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to acces it with phpmyadmin, but that doesn't work. But I'll try some of the suggestions below this afternoon. I will update this when I got the answer.

Comment: If Symfony2 can access to the database, PhpMyAdmin should be able to access the database too. You probably misconfigured PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: It is an open source system based on symfony2, so I didn't exactly configure it myself. I just installed the system, that's why I had troubles finding the database in the first place. But the /phpmyadmin just didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL as db server. You should use MySQL workbench. I don't understand why phpmyadmin is still exist.

Comment: MySQL workbench did the job. Get it hosted on VirtualBox, get the IP address and connect to the right datbase and voila.
Much easier then I had in mind, probably just thought way to difficult. Thanks!

Comment: *You should use MySQL workbench. I don't understand why phpmyadmin is still exist* What does that mean? Are you suggesting to **not use** PhPMyAdmin?

Comment: Correct. Phpmyadmin is not secure and lack of functions.

Comment: Can you add some references about that? Your answer doesn't explain this. Is it only a personal opinion?

Comment: MySQL workbench can leverage SSH tunnel to access DB. This makes it much secure than a web app. About features, I can't think of anything I can not do with workbench and can with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an database interface.

Natively Symfony do not provide this tool.
However, if your database is host on wamp/mamp/lamp there is no reason that you can't access with phpmyadmin.